# Specifying an unlimited number of arguments to a commanline option

Tags: python, command-line

In Python, is there a way to specify an unlimited number of arguments to a command line option ? For example something like `python myscript.py --use-files a b c d e`. Note that I strictly want to use a command line option e.g. I don't just want `python myscript.py a b c d e`

Comment: "Unlimited" isn't strictly true because the kernel has a constant `ARG_MAX` which is the maximum size of the arguments buffer under POSIX. But Python can take whatever the OS allows the caller to pass in, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Command-line options are simple with stdlib [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) module. Using `nargs="*"` allows arbitrarily many arguments to be supplied for an option:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--use-files', nargs='*', default=['a', 'b'])
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Outputs:

```
$ python /tmp/spam.py 
Namespace(use_files=['a', 'b'])
$ python /tmp/spam.py --use-files hello world
Namespace(use_files=['hello', 'world'])
$ python /tmp/spam.py --use-files aleph-null bottles of beer on the wall, aleph-null bottles of beer, take one down pass it around, aleph-null bottles of beer on the wall
Namespace(use_files=['aleph-null', 'bottles', 'of', 'beer', 'on', 'the', 'wall,', 'aleph-null', 'bottles', 'of', 'beer,', 'take', 'one', 'down', 'pass', 'it', 'around,', 'aleph-null', 'bottles', 'of', 'beer', 'on', 'the', 'wall'])
```